# Approximating Solution to Stochastic Integral

Tags: matlab, probability, differential-equations, stochastic

I am trying to approximate the solution to:

[image]

where [image] and [image] for both sides of this equation.

My code for the left side is:

```
N = 2000;  Tend = 2*pi;  dt = Tend/N;  t = 0:dt:Tend;
f = sin(t)*sqrt(dt);
f = [0 ff(1:end-1)];
[fL,junk] = meshgrid(f,1);
dW = cumsum([0 randn(1,N)].*fL,2);
```

but I can't figure out the right side at all, which is much harder. Can anyone help?

Comment: StackOverflow does not support LaTeX, so I took your syntax, rendered them as images and embedded them into your post.

Comment: fprime(s) = cos(s), b(s) = sum(randn(N * s/t,1 )*sqrt(dt)) and ds = dt... you should  use the same random numbers for the right and left side, naturally

Answer (score 0):

This looks more like the partial integration formula, or equivalent the product rule

```
(f*b)'=f'*b+f*b' or
d(f*b)=df*b+f*db = f'*b*dt+f*db
```

of differentiation, than any stochastic differential equation. In that sense there is nothing to solve there, except if you want to numerically verify the validity of the rule with `b` being a Wiener process.

Or you want to test the error of numerical methods. But then the first step would be to identify the numerical method, which appears to be the Euler or Euler-Maruyama method.

See [wikipedia: Euler-Maruyama method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maruyama_method), [wikipedia: Milstein method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milstein_method), and the very readable [P. Forsyth: An introduction to Computational Finance without Agonizing Pain.](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~paforsyt/agon.pdf)

---

For the Wiener process `b` you will need to keep the array of increments `db=randn(1,N)*sqrt(dt)` (and keep the root out of `f=sin(t)`). Then the left side is the sum over `f.*db` and for the right side you would need the array of partial sums over `db`, which in theory should be computed as

```
b(i+1)=b(i)+db(i)
```

Using the more expedient matlab function

```
b = cumsum(db)
```

will give you a shifted version where `b(i)=b(i-1)+db(i)`. In the grand total of the picture, this shift could lead to an error of magnitude `sqrt(dt)` which would only be important if you want to limit the error to magnitude `dt`.

After that operation, the terms on the right are `f(N)*b(N)-f(0)*b(0)` and the sum over `cos(t(i))*b(t(i))*dt(i)`, `i=0,...,N-1`.

Thus you compare on the left

```
cumsum(sin(t).*db)
```

and on the right

```
sin(t).*b - cumsum(cos(t).*b).*dt
```

and this should give almost identical values.

In matlab's cousin scilab the following script gives perfectly overlapping results:

```
N=6000; dt=2*%pi/N;

t=0:1:N; t=t*dt;

dW=rand(t,"normal")*sqrt(dt);
W = cumsum(dW);

f=sin(t); fp=cos(t);

ex1=cumsum(f.*dW);
ex2=f.*W;
ex3=cumsum(fp.*W).*dt;

clf;
subplot(211);
plot(t+5*dt,ex1,t,ex2-ex3)
subplot(212);
plot(t,ex2-ex1-ex3)
```

---

One can see the identity also directly in the discretization by application of index shifts. Setting `b=cumsum(db)`, `f=sin(t)` and `fp(t)=cos(t)` the derivative, the element `n` of `cumsum(f.*db)`  is and transforms as:

```
sum(i=1..n) f(i)*db(i) = sum(i=1..n) f(i)*(b(i)-b(i-1))

= -f(1)*b(0)+sum(i=1..n) (f(i)-f(i+1))*b(i) + f(n+1)*b(n)

= f(n)*b(n) - sum(i=1..n) fp(i)*b(i)*dt 
    + (f(n+1)-f(n))*b(n) - sum(i=1..n) (f(i+1)-f(i)-fp(i)*dt)*b(i)
```

with the virtual value `b(0)=0`. The next to last line contains the `n`th element of `f.*b-cumsum(fp.*b)*dt` and the last line the error terms of the discretization, with magnitudes `dt` and `(t(n)-t(1))*dt`.

Comment: Hm... maybe I should ask what's difference when I am generating db and just b, where b is a wiener process. This problem has made it clear that I don't think I understand the difference anymore.

Comment: db is white noise, b is the Wiener process, also known as Brownian motion (the physical Brownian motion is the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process, there are some misgivings in the naming scheme). If `dt(i)=t(i+1)-t(i)` then `db(i)=randn()*sqrt(dt(i))` and `b(i+1)=b(i)+db(i)`.

Comment: Yes, that is the usual definition of a Brownian motion.

Comment: How come you use sums? I was taught to use cumulative sums.

Comment: This is not exactly matlab syntax. I was not aware that `cumsum actually computes the array of partial sums. I had the documentation page open, but apparently read over it. Now you have only to deal with the conventions of the Ito integral resp. stochastic processes. cumsum([1 -1 -1 1]) is [1 0 -1 0] while the partial sums, adding forward as in b(i+1)=b(i)+db(i)`` should start with zero, [0 1 0 -1 0].

Comment: Damn, this just isn't working. I should get the same graph but I don't. Here is my code http://pastebin.com/pHuzvyCi

WR being the right side of the Integration by Parts and WL being the left side of the Integration by Parts.

Comment: I'm not sure why exactly `meshgrid` is used, but the line `[gL, junk] = meshgrid(f,1);` seems suspicious.

Comment: Ah, fixed that. but not much changed. :P

Comment: Please check again what originally was on the left and right side and what is in you script. There are 3 terms in the original identity.

Comment: Updated answer to incorporate the functionality of `cumsum` as intended in the question.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much LutzL. I actually made some very basic mistakes, but once I did the exact identity it worked perfect.